# Are internal navbar tabs considered links or buttons for accessibility purposes and what pseudo states do they require?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, accessibility

I have a website that has a navbar on the top of the page that tabs between large sections of the overall website. I also have a side nav bar for each of these large sections. The side nav bar correspondingly has tabs that can be clicked that reveal different types of content in the window. When each side nav bar tab is clicked the main nav bar tab the page is currently on remains static.

My question is whether or not the sidenav bar tabs should be considered links with an a tag or buttons for accessibility purposes? My understanding is that in both cases the button and link need a color change on hover, but would the sidenav bar tabs also require other pseudo states such as an underline or border?

I greatly appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interactive content should have a visible focus outline and, preferably, a hover state. But as you would not style these as links, but as tabs, I see no need for underlining or similar styling. That rule is merely for the links to stand out inside blocks of text, but I don’t expect your tabs to be easily confused with non-interactive textual content.

If the tabs change the URL, they should be links (or have a `role=“link”`).
If they do not, they can be whatever you like, but make sure to make them `role=“tab”` in a container with `role=“tabset”` in order to include most people in your solution.
And no matter what, make sure they are usable with keyboard. :-)

Comment: only if they change the url do they require underlining on hover?

Comment: Only if a clickable item appears as text inside a block of regular text, should it have extra styling - like underline - but not just on hover. It’s just important to be able to distinguish the link / text-button from the rest of the text, and if hover was required to do that, how would you know to hover this piece of text?